# Secure wcf (using username password validator) not working from php client

Tags: c#, php, wcf, ws-security

I have construct a simple secured wcf with `wsHttpBinding` in .Net C# (framework 4.5) and consume it from .Net C# (also) client and every thing work fine. **But** when I try to consume It from php (5.5) client by calling a method from the wcs service, the client not work **and it has entered in an infinite loop and not showing any error message**, just looping.
**a.** The following is my wcf `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`'s:

```
namespace CenteralServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IAdminServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
}
```

**b.** The following is the configueration file `Web.config` for the wcf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name= "CentralTicketServicesSystem.AdminSystem" 
                behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour">
                <endpoint address="AdminServices" 
                        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              contract="CentralTicketServicesSystem.IAdminServices"
              bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="MyEndPointBehavior">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/AdminServicesSystem" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <security mode="Message" >
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>

    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyEndPointBehavior">
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="customBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="CentralServicesHost.AuthorizationPolicy, CentralServicesHost" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
           customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CentralServicesHost.UserAuthentication, CentralServicesHost"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="15 63 10 5e b6 4b 4d 85 4b 2e 4d 5b ec 85 02 ec"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"
                            storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>

            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**c.** The following is `UserAuthentication` class:

```
namespace CentralServicesHost
{
    public class UserAuthentication : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {

        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

            if (userName != "test" && password != "test")
                 throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password.");
        }
    }
}
```

**d.** The following is `AuthorizationPolicy` class:

```
namespace CentralServicesHost
{
    public class AuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
    {
        Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        // this method gets called after the authentication stage
        public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
        {
            // get the authenticated client identity
            IIdentity client = GetClientIdentity(evaluationContext);
            // set the custom principal
            evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new CustomPrincipal(client);
            return true;
        }
        private IIdentity GetClientIdentity(EvaluationContext ec)
        {
            object obj;
            if (!ec.Properties.TryGetValue("Identities", out obj))
                throw new Exception("No Identity found");
            IList<IIdentity> identities = obj as IList<IIdentity>;
            if (identities == null || identities.Count <= 0)
                throw new Exception("No Identity found");
            return identities[0];
        }

        public System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet Issuer
        {
            get { return ClaimSet.System; }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id.ToString(); }
        }
    }
}
```

**e.** The following is `CustomPrincipal` class:

```
namespace CentralServicesHost
{
    class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        IIdentity _identity;
        string[] _roles;

        public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
        {
            _identity = identity;
        }

        // helper method for easy access (without casting)
        public static CustomPrincipal Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Thread.CurrentPrincipal as CustomPrincipal;
            }
        }

        public IIdentity Identity
        {
            get { return _identity; }
        }

        // return all roles
        public string[] Roles
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureRoles();
                return _roles;
            }
        }

        // IPrincipal role check
        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            EnsureRoles();
            return (_roles != null) ? _roles.Contains(role) : false;
        }

        // read Role of user from database
        protected virtual void EnsureRoles()
        {
            using (var s = new SupportedMaterialsSystemEntities())
            {
                _roles = new string[1] { "admin" };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**f.** The following is my php client code:

```
<?php
$options = array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
                  'login'      =>  'test',
                  'password'   =>  'test');
$wsdl = "http://localhost:8080/AdminServicesSystem";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->x = 3;
$obj->y = 3;
$retval = $client->Add($obj);//here the browser loops for infinite without any response.
//var_dump($exc);//THIS POINT NOT REACHED
//die();
$result = $retval->AddResult;
echo $result;
```

***NOTES:***
**1.** My OS is Win. 8.1, and I'm using visual studio 2013 (as adminstrator) and php Wamp Server.
**2.** I tried both, hosting the wcf service in IIS 6.2 and console application but non of them changes my php client looping.
**3.** I have Created the self-signed certificate usin the IIS manager that stores it in my local machine.
 
**4.** When I change the `soap_version` in the php code from `SOAP_1_2` to `SOAP_1_1` I had `Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.`.
**Last Note:**
My .Net C# Client code is the following:

```
 using (var svcProxy = new AdminServiceProxy.AdminServicesSystemClient())
        {
            svcProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            svcProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
            Console.WriteLine(svcProxy.Add(1, 1));//the service works fine and print 2
        }
 }
```

So agin, What is the right way to call a secured wcf (with `wsHttpBinding`) service from php.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a default WSDL metadata published to use PHP soap client (see abilities here http://php.net/manual/en/intro.soap.php).

Try to add endpoint with `basicHttpBinding` binding, which can provide WSDL for your client and then use this endpoint.

On the address http://localhost:8080/AdminServicesSystem you have endpoint with `mexHttpBinding`, which provides metadata int other format (http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-ws-metadata-exchange-20090317/).

Try to see here form more details: https://abhishekdv.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/mexhttpbinding-vs-wsdl/

Comment: Actually this way didn't work even when I saved the wsdl in local machine and route SoapClient to read it from the saved version.

Comment: Then try wireshark to catch the communication and see what is really happening.